.Net Core 8 Clean Architecture, Using Unit of work and Generic Repository pattern causes a DI problem
A simple .Net core 8 Clean Architecture project. I'm using the Repository pattern with Unit of Work.
I've a problem with DI. Would you please have a look on the images for a better understanding?!

namespace Restaurants.Domain.Contracts;
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();
}

namespace Restaurants.Domain.Contracts;

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Repos
    public IGenericRepository<Restaurant> RestaurantRepository { get; }
    #endregion

    public bool Save();
    public Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
}

namespace Restaurants.Infrastructure.Repositories;

internal class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private readonly RestaurantsDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(RestaurantsDbContext context, DbSet<TEntity> dbSet)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync() { // Code}
}

namespace Restaurants.Infrastructure.Repositories;
internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly RestaurantsDbContext _context;
    private IGenericRepository<Restaurant> _restaurantRepository;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public UnitOfWork(
        RestaurantsDbContext context,
        IGenericRepository<Restaurant> restaurantRepository
    )
    {
        _context = context;
        _restaurantRepository = restaurantRepository;
    }

    public IGenericRepository<Restaurant> RestaurantRepository => _restaurantRepository;
}

namespace Restaurants.Infrastructure.Extensions;
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<RestaurantsDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IRestaurantSeeder, RestaurantSeeder>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));

        return services;
    }
}

namespace Restaurants.Application.Services;

public class RestaurantsService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public RestaurantsService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Restaurant>> GetAllRestaurantsAsync()
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.RestaurantRepository.GetAllAsync();
    }
}

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

#region Swagger
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
#endregion

#region DI container Configs
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration)
.AddApplication();
#endregion



Using the Repository pattern with Unit of Work, however there is a problem with the DI when trying to call Unit Of Work within the ResturantService class.

Please don't post images of code and images of exceptions.

Either way, your question seems like a duplicate of Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate.

It's hard to see, but where are you registering the RestaurantService with the container?

There is no need to implement the Unit of Work or Repository pattern when using Entity Framework as it does so already. All you're doing is adding additional complexity for zero value.

It seems to be an erro with the Singletone.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495333/asp-net-core-repository-dependency-injection-fails-on-singleton-injection
